# Check if phone call is successfull in React Native

Tags: java, android, react-native

I need to check some phone numbers to make sure they are still active. Unfortunately I have no idea how to approach this problem.

My only idea is to record phone call and try to detect dialing sound in recorded file. But can this be even done in react native? Google only tells me how to record sounds from mic, so this wont work for dialing tone.

Is there any way to do it in React Native? If not, can this be done in Java?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend doing this on the backend with Java. You're going to want to use a library like [Asterisk](https://www.asterisk.org/) unless of course you want to have your own implementation.